# Converting a Maildir to a PST

Tags: linux, exchange, convert, outlook, maildir

Does anyone know of any solutions to convert a Maildir to a PST in linux? I'm able to use a program in Windows called Aid4Mail, but that requires me to pull the Maildir down from the server. I've got a bunch of users' boxes to convert, so that route isn't ideal.

All my users are remote, so it's not like I can just use Outlook to connect to the IMAP server and export as PST from their machines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are projects like [libpst](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/) allowing access to PST files from within Linux, but I doubt that anything aside from Microsoft's tools themselves will give you a "clean" PST output.

I cannot see though why you could not connect to the IMAP server using Outlook from *your* machine and simply copy the messages to one or more PST stores mounted in Outlook - this is going to produce predictably valid results. If you are concerned about the number of manual operations needed for that task, you might consider using Outlook VBA to script [folder recursion](http://www.vboffice.net/sample.html?mnu=2&smp=12&cmd=showitem&lang=en&pub=6) and message copying using the [CopyTo method](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/rdomail.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this but it looks workable.

> Well it's convoluted, but I think the route is to convert maildir to
>   mbox (that's a piece of cake and can be done with a bash script) then
>   to convert the mbox file to eml format using mbox2eml Outlook can then
>   open the eml format and import it to pst.

- http://myreader.co.uk/msg/102897704.aspx
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/a-script-to-convert-maildir-to-mailbox-format-381568/

Comment: Outlook 2016 seems to be only able to open the eml files one by one. To the point that I had to use a reverse route (eml > maildir > IMAP server) to import mails from Windows Live Mail to Outook